# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline with extended choice parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I tried out to implement my first Declarative Pipeline with Jenkins to be able to put also the parameter definitions of a job under SCM.

I wanted to transfer an existing job that has an extended choice paraemter. Unfortunately I was not able to add it to the parameters{...} section of my script.

On the plugin page: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin I found a comment that stated it should be possible by:

```
import com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended_choice_parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition

def type = "PT_JSON"
def groovyScript  = null
def propertyValue  = null
def projectName = null
def propertyFile = null
def groovyScriptFile = "/path_to/script.groovy"
... 
def extendedChoice = new ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition(name,
            type,
            propertyValue,
            projectName,
            propertyFile,
            groovyScript,
.....

input message: 'Param1', parameters: [extendedChoice]
```

Unfortunately this was not working for me. "input Requested" gave a non specified error. While I could live with an "input message" solution, it was not what I was looking for in the first place. I want to add this parameter to the parameter section as mentioned already. But I am not able to find any place where this is described. Any suggestions how to go on, or maybe also alternative approaches/plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what i used and Tested sucessfully for Single parameter you might need to convert it for Json

```
com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended_choice_parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition extch =new com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended_choice_parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition( "NAME", "PT_SINGLE_SELECT", "VALUE, a, b", null, null, null, null, null,null, null,null,null, null, null, null,null, null, null,null, null, null, null, null, null, null,null,false,false,2,"DESC", "," )
```

Comment: thanks for this. But it feels not completely right. I hope they will support it in the futere somehow. So still hoping for a miracle.

Comment: @Matthias, did you learn more on this? I'm eager to use Extended Choice Parameters in my declarative pipelines, and struggling to find good information on the simplest path forward.

Comment: @timblaktu no nothing new. For our very complex parameters we decided to put javascript in the job description and implement our own logic inside JS

Answer (score 4):

You should go to your `http://jenkins-url.com/pipeline-syntax` on the `Sample step` dropdown select `properties` There is a checkbox for `This project is parameterized` then you can select `Add parameter` `Extended Choice Parameter` and you can generate the groovy for that for your pipeline.

Comment: But this is only working for 'scripted pipelines' not for 'declarative pipelines' or am I wrong? ... even if it was working, it always only generates this: properties([parameters([<object of type com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended_choice_parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition>]), pipelineTriggers([])])

Comment: Supposedly, I heard extended choice parameter is not supported and there is a ticket on their board about it. But I have not been able to find it to share if I do I'll let you know.